# Return Quantity is not decreasing in pos odoo 12

Tags: python, odoo-12

In Odoo Point of sale front-end when i am returning a order the order gets returned and the quantity of some orders remains same (i.e. when i put a order no from pos if the porduct quantity initially is 20 if i return 2 items in that order no it doesnot decrease when i return a product its still remains 20)it doesnot happens on every orders it happens in some  few orders. I also figured out the problem there was no return_qty key in the dict of the order no for that it always return the original qty for the code i edited

```
    def load_return_order_lines(self, pos_order_id):
    valid_return_lines = []
    current_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    if pos_order_id:
        print('1111111', pos_order_id)
        order_id = self.env['pos.order'].browse(pos_order_id)
        print('2222222', order_id)
        # print('6666666666666', self.env['pos.order.line'].search([('id', '=', pos_order_id), ('return_qty', '>', 0)]))
        if order_id and order_id.config_id.enable_print_valid_days:
            print('33333333333', order_id, order_id.config_id.enable_print_valid_days)
            order_lines = self.search([('order_id', '=', pos_order_id), ('return_qty', '>', 0)])
            if order_lines:
                print('44444444444444', order_lines)
                for line in order_lines:
                    if line.return_valid_days > 0 and not line.product_id.is_dummy_product:
                        date_N_days_after = (
                            (order_id.date_order + timedelta(days=line.return_valid_days))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                        if current_date <= date_N_days_after:
                            valid_return_lines.append(line.read()[0])
                            print('555555555555', valid_return_lines)
        else:
            dict = self.search_read([('order_id', '=', pos_order_id),  ('price_subtotal', '>', 0)])
            for rec in dict:
                if rec.get('return_qty') <= 0 or 'return_qty' not in rec.keys():
                    rec['return_qty'] = rec.get('qty')
            for rec in dict:
                print(rec['return_qty'])
            return dict
    return valid_return_lines
```

please anyone help me out here that if there will be no "return_qty" in the "order_id" then it will take the value of the field "qty" and how should i pass the return_qty to that id so that the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Your checks for the existence of 'return_qty' are not safe. Do the get() first and check for None. Then put a debug print() to show what you're assigning when return_qty either doesn't exist or is less than 0

Comment: there are no none value bro i checked that earlier

Comment: i just want that if there will be no return order then return_qty = qty
and for the returns the return quantity should decrease...